# array indexing with MIPS

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, mips, arrayaccess

I have a bit of trouble with array indexing in MIPS. Lets say I have the following C code:

```
void main() {
.
.
int[2] a; # or any other length
.
.
a[1] = 7; # or any other number
.
.
}
```

Lets say I know that 'a' offset from the frame pointer is for example 12, so that:

```
lw t0, -12($fp)
```

Gives me the base address of 'a'. 
Now lets say the array access index value (in this case 1) is stored in $t1. But I don't what it is. How can I store 7 in a[1]? I am looking for something like:

```
mul $t1, $t1, -4      # since each integer takes 4 bytes
addi $t1, $t1, -12    # t1 = exact offset from $fp to a[1]
li $t2, 7             # t2 = 7
sw $t2, $t1($fp)
```

The problem is the last operation is illegal (despite [Integer array indexing with MIPS assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158132/integer-array-indexing-with-mips-assembly)). How can I do this? Thank you

Comment: Add it separately using `add`, that is `add $t1, $t1, $fp` then `sw $t2, ($t1)`.

Comment: @Jester Thanks. Sorry I was being stupid. Haven't slept for quite some time :)